# Visual Studio code is not loading my python interpreters

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've been using a python interpreter that I set in my venv the whole time for this project. Recently I changed my python interpreter which I've set as a default interpreter in my user settings like the vs docs [vs code python environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) describes it and also set in my JSON settings file refuses to load instead. I'm getting the default conda python interpreter with no other options.

here is my Json file:

settings.json

```
{
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:/Users/houst/Envs/Mach/Scripts/python.exe"
}
```

Comment: Try installing the python package from the extensions tab

Comment: I uninstalled it and reinstalling but I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried using double backslashes instead since that's what windows file paths need (as shown in the documentation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the `\` instead of the `/` in the path. For safety just copy paste the path from the windows explorer. 
**Another Solution** :  Writing the path in Json should definitely work. But I prefer using the functionality vscode provides. Now come to my solution.
press `ctrl+shift+p` to open the search bar. now type `>Python:Select Interpreter`. This should allow you to select the existing interpreter or to add the interpreter path in the vscode.
I'm attaching a screen shot for your convenient.

[image: VsCode Python Interpreter]

*You should keep in mind that, if you add the Python interpreted path in environment path of your system, vscode should automatically find the interpreter.*