# Installing gmsh module in virtual enviroment python

Tags: python, virtualenv, gmsh

I am using a virtual environment for my python code. I installed the gmsh module inside the folder project\venv\lib\site-packages, and apparently, it is done properly since when I create the "requirement.txt" it appears within the required modules. However, when I open the project folder in Visual Studio Code, and I try to import the gmsh module, it is not found.

Can you give me some hints??

-- Edit
[installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khYq6.png)
[vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBPfB.png)

Comment: could you post screen of pip install gmsh from your terminal?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would help to share a screenshot (by editing your answer to include one) of the VS Code application. It is probably the case that you need to select the version of python you installed and it will be easy to point this out with a screenshot.

Comment: @KarolMilewczyk, I added screenshoots as you suggested ! Thank you a lot

Comment: @TCArlen I added new screenshoots, thank you

Comment: You can install modules easily when you first activate virtual environment and then using pip install without that target part.

Comment: Thank you all, I solved the issue. I needed to activate my virtual environment :)

Answer (score 0):

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71192783/1011253) suggest, you need to set your Python interpreter in VS Code.

You should select `project\venv\bin\python` as your interpreter

Comment: @MarialauraLeonardi did it solve your issue?